# Java reflection for DragSource method

Tags: java, reflection, drag-and-drop

Implementing drag and drop operations for a Java NetBeans app, I'd like to call the following static method that's in the source code for the DragSource object:

**SunDragSourceContextPeer.setDragDropInProgress(false);**

However, when I try to drop this line into a DragSource listener, I get the error message:

"Package sun.awt.dnd is not visible (package sun.awt.dnd is declared in module java.desktop, which does not export it to the unnamed module)"

Is there a way around this? Perhaps using reflection?

Comment: You are not supposed to call this method. [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: Unfortunately, in the Mac implementation of DragSource/DragGestureRecognizer, something's not getting reset properly in cases where the mouse is released outside the source component. The result is that next time you click inside the component, you see the drag cursor immediately - there's no waiting for an actual drag gesture. I've tried: DGR's resetRecognizer() method, but it seems to have no effect. The flawed behavior is intermittent. And again,  it's not present at all in Windows implementations.

Comment: So, a perfect example of XY problem.

Comment: So is there another way around this? Any suggestion would be most appreciated.

Comment: I don’t know, but the first step to find out, is to open a question about the Drag&Drop problem rather than asking how to invoke a specific non-API method via Reflection. If there are people knowing the answer for the Java/MacOS/Drag&Drop problem, they currently don’t know that you have the question.